# How do Django authorization decorators (such as: login required) work?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to better understand "behind the scenes" of the Django authorization decorators.
Although I think I understand decorators in general, I find it difficult to understand the authorization decorators code.
Is there any "line by line" explanation of the code (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anywhere that has a line-by-line documentation of these decorators, but here's my take on it.

```py
def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
```

This function serves as the basis for Django's decorator based authentication.
It accepts a test function which will have the user passed to it to determine
whether or not that user has access to the decorated view.

```py
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

This chunk of code is just standard Python decorator stuff - if you understand
decorators there's not really anything to explain.

```py
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here the test function is called with the user. If the user passes the test
the original view function is immediately returned and no further action is
taken.

```py
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Retrieve the current request's url and the login url. The login url can be
passed to the `user_passes_test` decorator or the default value in the Django
settings can be used.

```py
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
```

Retrieve the HTTP scheme (http or https) and the netloc ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) plus
the port if applicable) from both the current url and the login url.

```py
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                    (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
```

If the HTTP scheme and the netloc for the two urls match then the path is set
to the relative url rather than the absolute url.

```py
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
```

Redirect the request to the login page. `redirect_to_login` will send the user
to get logged in with a `?next=` GET parameter equal to the current path.

```py
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

Finishing decorator stuff.

`login_required` is just a shortcut for `user_passes_test` which already supplies the `test_func` - a simple function which checks the value of `user.is_authenticated`.

`permission_required` Does the same but takes the name of a permission or a list of permission names and checks that the user has those permissions. `permission_required` also has the added feature that you can pass `raise_exception=True` to raise a 403 instead of redirecting to the login url.